# Pagination with React.js

Tags: json, reactjs, pagination

Right now I'm stuck with pagination implementation with React. I have all the neccessary data from JSON, however I got no result.
Here's the code I use:
first, I fetch data from the server:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {items: {}, totalPages: [], nextPage: []};
}
componentDidMount() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8000/items?json=true';
    request.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            items: response.body.items.data,
            totalPages: response.body.items.last_page,
            nextPage: response.body.items.next_page_url
        });
    });
}
```

Thus I get a simple JSON file:

```
{
  "items": {
    "total": 26025,
    "per_page": 16,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1627,
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/items?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 16,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
 }
}
```

I successfully display `items` data in `render` method like this:

```
let items = _.map(this.state.items, (item) => {
        return (
                <div key={item.id}>
                        <div className="content">
                            <span>
                                {item.type}
                            </span>
                            ...
                        </div>
                </div>
        )
    });
```

and then `return` it like so:

```
return (
        <div>
           {items}
        </div>
        <div>
           <a href={this.state.nextPage}>Next</a>
        </div>
)
```

I can see that URL changes after I press `Next` button to `page2` but there are two issues: I want to change `items` components based on JSON file when I click `Next` (i.e first page contains the first set of 16 elements, second page contains the second set) but there is no change and when I click `Next` button again but on the second page (according to URL) it doesn't get me to the third page and so on.
I know I need to somehow bind these state to `page2` URL shows content described on the second page and I ran through tutorials but they seem to be outdated in case I use `React 15.2.1`.
I would appreciate any help or a thought that'd help me to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to your link element and pass the url as parameter. In the handler function make the ajax request and update the states using setState (similar to the one u did it on componentDidMount).

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      totalPages: '',
      nextPage: ''
    };
    this._loadData = this._loadData.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/items?json=true';
    this._loadData(url);

  }
  _loadData(url) {
    request.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        items: response.body.items.data,
        totalPages: response.body.items.last_page,
        nextPage: response.body.items.next_page_url
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    let items = _.map(this.state.items, (item) => {
    return (
            <div key={item.id}>
                    <div className="content">
                        <span>
                            {item.type}
                        </span>
                        ...
                    </div>
            </div>
    )
});
    return (
        <div>
           {items}
        </div>
        <div>
           <a href="#0" onClick={this._loadData(this.state.nextPage)}>Next</a>
        </div>
)
  }
```

Comment: Hey Galeel, thanks for response!
Unfortunately it doesn't work after I make a link to the next page giving me a console error "cannot read property 'items' of null". Seems like the link is taking me to the next page but the state of items doesn't change, request output shows that data in json document is null

Comment: what's the response you are getting when you hit http://localhost:8000/items?page=2 in the addressbar.? Are u getting the JSON response similar to the one you posted above.?

Comment: First of all thanks for dedicating your time, I really appreciate it!
I test response with Postman and here is what I found. In JSON document I get next_page_url as "?page=2" but as you probably saw my first requrest is made with "?json=true" parameter to load data. Navigating to "?page=2" gives me nothing but when I navigate to "?page=2?json=true" I get exactly what I want. I contacted my backend dev to make changes, but I'm just curious is it possible to add "?json=true" to nextPage when I set state?

Comment: Yes,you can do normal string concatenation using '+' operator. So in your case, at setState do something like this: `response.body.items.next_page_url + '?json=true'`